# why can't I un-install or re-install applications using Web Platform Installer?

Tags: web-platform-installer

I am having problems with IIS Express so I have decided to try and un-install or re-install the application in web platform installer.  The only problem is there doesn't seem to be a way of un-installing or installing the application again.  Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find those installation file in %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers, I un-install them manually. IIS Express you can un-install in control panel, it is in the list...